# How to set an attribute to Array in Model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, model, attributes, migrate

Can you teach me how to set an attribute to Array in Model?.

I have tried it but when I use array's method like `push`, `each`, I got the error `` undefined method `push' for nil:NilClass ``

My migrate look like this:

```
class CreateContacts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :contacts do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :email
      t.string :email_confirmation
      t.integer :city_ids, array: true
      t.text :description

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

I would like to set attribute `city_ids` to Array.

Comment: have you check this one http://reefpoints.dockyard.com/ruby/2012/09/18/rails-4-sneak-peek-postgresql-array-support.html

Comment: Thank you, but It still not work for me, I can't use array method in attribute which set to be an array

Answer (score 3):

One important thing to note when interacting with array (or other mutable values) on a model. ActiveRecord does not currently track "destructive", or in place changes. These include array pushing and poping, advance-ing DateTime objects.
Example

```
 john = User.create(:first_name => 'John', :last_name => 'Doe',
  :nicknames => ['Jack', 'Johnny'])

john = User.first

john.nicknames += ['Jackie boy']
# or
john.nicknames = john.nicknames.push('Jackie boy')
# Any time an attribute is set via `=`, ActiveRecord tracks the change
john.save
```

Referrence - [link](http://reefpoints.dockyard.com/ruby/2012/09/18/rails-4-sneak-peek-postgresql-array-support.html)

Answer (score 1):

You need to set a default. Otherwise, the attribute is `nil`, until you give it a value:

```
  t.integer :city_ids, array: true, default: []
```

Or, you need to give it a value befor eyou attempt to use it:

```
c = City.find(...)

c.city_ids ||= []

c.city_ids.push(...)
```

Comment: I use that array attribute for multiple check box, I have some checkbox and when it checked, array attribute will add value into.
But I still can't use array method like "push, first, last" because NoMethodError